# How to add specific PHP code in HTML?

Tags: php, html

I read the article "[Fix Bad value X-UA-Compatible once and for all](http://www.validatethis.co.uk/news/fix-bad-value-x-ua-compatible-once-and-for-all/)" and in try to fix the wrong display in IE, but it's not working, maybe I incorrectly inserted the following code:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) &amp;&amp; 
(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))
    header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1');
```

[image]

In IE it's just a comment:
[image]

Comment: php code should be in <?php ----  ?>

Comment: and it doesnt work with `index.html` should be a php file... http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: You can't just add php code in HTML. Your web-server needs to "understand" php, then you could include it in `<?php` ... `?>` brackets.

Comment: Already tried `<?php` ... `?>`  in head and body, still in IE page doesn't working. If I try to put only `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>`, everything is OK, except the validation check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add a `<meta>` only for IE,This can use without creating a php file.
Try this code insted of your php code.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: How did you check?meta is not added?or any other issues?

Comment: IE not understanding it

Comment: Nope, with or without. Update the main post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your php code within php tags. It also looks like you're inserting php into a file with a .html extension, unless your server is configured to treat this as php you will probably want to look at that as well.